# AbortController: how to stop instead of abort a Node.js stream?

Tags: node.js, node-streams, abortcontroller

My application has two buttons: start (to consume a stream from the server) and stop (to close the connection using `AbortController`). Here are my listeners:

```js
let abortController = new AbortController();

start.addEventListener('click', async () => {
  const readable = await consumeAPI(abortController.signal);
  readable.pipeTo(appendToHTML(cards));
});

stop.addEventListener('click', () => {
  abortController.abort();
  console.log('aborting...');
  abortController = new AbortController();
})
```

However, I would like to change the behavior of these buttons to pause and resume the request instead of abort and close.

AbortController [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController) seems to have only the `abort()` and no other alternatives.

My server is using `Readable.toWeb()` from Node streams. I know there is a `pause()` and `resume()` function but I don't know how to use or how to call them from the client.